# Jinja2 get/import WTF-Form into Basic.html (which is included on every other html page)

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms

I have created a form with  WTF-Forms:

```
class ContactForm(FlaskForm):
    report = TextAreaField('Nachricht', validators=[DataRequired(message="Geben Sie Ihre Nachricht ein")])
    contact_email = TextField('Ihre Email')
```

I need this form on every page in my flask app, it is in the footer.

The server creates the html pages with `render_template`:

```
# Index
@app.route('/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def index():   
    form_contact_us = ContactForm(prefix="contact-us-form") 
    return render_template('index.html', form_contact_us=form_contact_us)
```

I usually give all forms, which I use to `render_template`. But if I do this I will need to implement this on EVERY function, which gives HTML to the client. I could do this, but I feel like there should be a better and faster solution. I was not able to find a solution myself, maybe someone knows it.

P.S.:

I have a `basic.html` which is used by every other html page. I use this form in the `basic.html`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to inject the form into all jinja templates by using `context_processor`. This ensures that the `contact_form` form variable is present in all your templates.

```
@app.context_processor
def inject_contact_form():
    return dict(contact_form=ContactForm(prefix="contact-us-form"))
```

In your `basic.html` you can then render the form as usual:

```
{{ contact_form.report.label }}<br>
{{ contact_form.report(size=32) }}
```